# Translate from chinese to english during search

Tags: search, translate

I m programming a web application(FrontEnd-React & HTML,BackEnd- Go lang) where some of the people who use this application will know only Chinese not English . By default the search in the web application is done in English.

In database i wanted to store only the English details of the items.If the people who know only Chinese,search in Chinese and i need to translate it in to English before submitting to the server to get the items related to the search.

Is it a right way to do this or do i need to store both the english and chinese details in the database!!!!

Is it possible??If can please let me know the name of the plugin to add in my web application and i m open for any suggestions for this.....
Appreciate any help.
Thanks......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so if you and change just de html text to other language you can use this 
 the browser like google translate automatic for the user language if you need be more specific about the language use 
https://translate.google.com/manager/website/

if you want translate before user request  you should use

https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/

in the quiqckstart file you have something like

{
  'q': 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.',
  'source': 'en',
  'target': 'es',
  'format': 'text'
}

so before send request this translate for the target language